# Handle a save dialog pop up and save to disk

Tags: jmeter

I am performance testing a reporting system where you enter information and generate a report. The issue I have is the report is generated as a PDF file and presents a Save Dialog box.

As part of the test I would like to save the PDF file to disk. How can I do this?

Edit: Below is the dialog box I get when I click a button to download the report.

[image]

I need to somehow simulate clicking the "Save File" radio button and then "OK"

Comment: describe better your problem

Comment: It is possible to save the file to the disk by writing a custom `post processor` to the request. If you provide more details, I can assist you.

Comment: @rafael I have updated with a screenshot of the dialog box I encounter when generating a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Save Response to a file" lister to save the pdf.

Check below screenshot for reference.
[image]

[Link](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) for further information.

Note while using this you dont have to worry about click a button. Your will get pdf in response and that will be save by the above listener.

Click on save is not sending any request to the server and hence it will not be recorded in jmeter.

Hope this helps.